# How to access an external SFTP from Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, google-compute-engine, pysftp

I'm setting a process using python on GCE that must connect to my local SFTP and copy files from there.

I'm using pysftp but getting a SSH problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> import pysftp    
>>> sftp = pysftp.Connection(host, username=user, password=pasw)

Exception AttributeError: "'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'" in <bound method Connection.__del_
_ of <pysftp.Connection object at 0x7feaa86c5b90>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host sftp.mynet.com found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manualy adding the SSH Key to known_hosts did the trick.

```
$ ssh sftp.mydomain.com
```

Would appreciate if someone post a solution where pysftp do this automaticaly

Comment: You can run something like ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p 998 ftp.coremetrics.com  > ~/.ssh/known_hosts to add you hostname as known host automatically.